# Scale Qml button text depending on button size

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt6, qtquickcontrols2

I want to to scale a button's text with respect to its height:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.10

ToolButton {
    id: btn
    font.pixelSize: implicitHeight*0.8 // Binding loop detected for property "font.pixelSize"
    
    contentItem: Text {
        text: btn.text
        font: btn.font
    }
}
```

This sometimes works but more often a binding loop is detected because when the font size changes, also the button size changes. What is the correct way for scaling the text size?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Use "height" instead of "implicitHeight".

And the ToolButton's height is bound to the font size by default, so you need to set a height for your button.

Comment: Using ``height`` has the same result.

Comment: Did you set the „height“ property of your ToolButton to something? 
Because i just tested this and it worked!

Comment: I see what you mean but I need the inverse. For instance, when the button is placed in a Layout (or some other container adjusting the size) and its size is changed then I want to adjust the button's text size too.  I do not see that the button text size changes at all when the button is resized - I have to manually adjust the font size.

Comment: Okay, this is a special case, because the Layout has a lot of attached properties and manipulates it's child items.
If you provide me a reproducible code with the Layout item that you are using, i may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

One method to avoid the binding loop is not use declarative code but imperative instead. For this, we watch for `onWidthChanged` and `onHeightChanged` and invoke `resize()`. Our resize routine we compute a scale using a fixed `TextMetric` at a reference font size. With that we can size the text accordingly:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Page {
    anchors.fill: parent

    ToolButton {
        id: btn
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: parent.height / 2
        text: qsTr("Hello")
        property TextMetrics tm: TextMetrics {
            font.pixelSize: 20
            text: btn.text
        }
        onWidthChanged: Qt.callLater(resize)
        onHeightChanged: Qt.callLater(resize)
        function resize() {
            let fx = width / tm.width * tm.font.pixelSize * 0.8;
            let fy = height / tm.height * tm.font.pixelSize * 0.8;
            font.pixelSize = Math.min(fx, fy)
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?code=import%20QtQuick%202.15%0Aimport%20QtQuick.Controls%202.15%0A%0APage%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20anchors.fill%3A%20parent%0A%0A%20%20%20%20ToolButton%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%20btn%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20anchors.centerIn%3A%20parent%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width%3A%20parent.width%20%2F%202%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20height%3A%20parent.height%20%2F%202%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20qsTr(%22Hello%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20property%20TextMetrics%20tm%3A%20TextMetrics%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20font.pixelSize%3A%2020%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text%3A%20btn.text%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onWidthChanged%3A%20Qt.callLater(resize)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onHeightChanged%3A%20Qt.callLater(resize)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20resize()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20fx%20%3D%20width%20%2F%20tm.width%20*%20tm.font.pixelSize%20*%200.8%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20fy%20%3D%20height%20%2F%20tm.height%20*%20tm.font.pixelSize%20*%200.8%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20font.pixelSize%20%3D%20Math.min(fx%2C%20fy)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)